# Trying to "registerSuite" asynchronously in intern

Tags: javascript, requirejs, intern

I'm trying to load several files that are all of a certain type to run tests on individually.
To do this, I'm looping through the require config and getting all the files under a path.

The root of the issue seems to be that I'm calling require (from requirejs) which uses a callback, and within that callback I'm calling registerSuite. The intern process is finishing before the tests ever register.

In pseudocode:

```
define(['intern!object' ...
    function(registerSuite ...

    for (var key in paths) {
        require([paths[key]], function(module) {
            registerSuite({
                name: 'Tests for ' + key
...
```

Is there any good way to make sure the suite is registered properly?

Thank you.